# Email client with zoom functionality

Tags: email

Is there any email client for Windows that supports zooming of HTML messages while viewing? This should work even for message-specific font sizes are set (for example, "Large/Largest" setting in IE/Windows Live Mail has no effect in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Windows Live Mail but Outlook 2007 supports zooming with ctrl+scroll wheel.

Comment: Well, it is a bit too heavy ;-) I know I did not set any restrictions, but that's because I'd like to choose from several suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

[Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/) supports <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>−</kbd>.